# Making background element out of a part of a video

Tags: video, after-effects, video-editor, mask

I have this shot which has the right door color corrected to make it look dark and red :

[image]

How would I go about making it part of the "background" so that when someone comes in front of it, he is not affected by the correction like in the shot below :

[image]

I tried looking into Masks as background or 3D layers but couldn't seem to find what I'm looking for. I'm sure it's an easy thing to do but I just need guidance on what to look / search for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to rotoscope every object in front of your "background". There is not simple solution, because AE cant tell the difference between you foreground and background. Even I can't tell, because people drop shadows on your "background", etc.

You can try to use [rotobrush](https://helpx.adobe.com/after-effects/using/roto-brush-refine-matte.html) for that, but if you have there a lot of people, it will require a lot of work.

Comment: Ok but once I track the motion of the person coming in front what do I do with him to tell AE "this person shouldn't be affected b the mask"

Comment: Put it in a new layer above your video and adjustment layer. So adjustment layer can't affect it.